# Separate icon sets for GTK+2 and GTK+3 applications on Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, themes, icons, gtk3, gtk-2

I use the Breeze Dark theme on Kubuntu, which also works perfectly with GTK+2 applications, but it's not fully supported on GTK+3 applications like Firefox yet.

Because of that, I've set my system to use Breeze Dark for GTK+2 programs, and the light Breeze for GTK+3 programs.

However, the KDE settings window (GNOME Application Style) only lets me pick a single icon pack for both versions. Is it possible to use different icon sets for them? The "fallback theme" option doesn't work for that.

Comment: Please don't cross-post. If you want this moved to another site like [unix:se] then please flag your post.

Comment: @phk I've got that post removed already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have KDE installed right now to test. As I remember with Kubuntu 15.04, KDE was creating two files to override GTK theme settings.

GTK2:

```
~/.gtkrc-2.0
```

GTK3:

```
~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini
```

As they are two separate file you can change them differently. But you may need to change them to read-only so KDE config tool will not able to change them.

I could find a reference with example: [Archlinux Wiki - GTK](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GTK%2B#Basic_theme_configuration)

> ### Basic theme configuration
>
> To manually change the GTK+ theme, icons, font and font size, add the
>   following to the configuration files, for example:
>
> **GTK+ 2:**
>
> ```
> ~/.gtkrc-2.0
>
> gtk-icon-theme-name = "Adwaita"
> gtk-theme-name = "Adwaita"
> gtk-font-name = "DejaVu Sans 11"
> ```
>
> **GTK+ 3:**
>
> ```
> $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/gtk-3.0/settings.ini
>
> [Settings]
> gtk-icon-theme-name = Adwaita
> gtk-theme-name = Adwaita
> gtk-font-name = DejaVu Sans 11
> ```
>
> **Note:** The icon theme name is the name defined in the theme's index file, not the name of its directory.